# CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF with Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a hierarchical set-up going on a table using the whole `START WITH` and `CONNECT BY` clauses, which I am using to set-up a vertical-aligned menu system that can expand out to the right, depending on if a menu option has children and the total number of Levels. Also, as part of the menu option, if a parent has children, I also display a `'>'` symbol to specify this.

My question is, I am using `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` to determine whether a menu option is a leaf or not but I also have a column in my hierarchical table that specifies whether the menu option is active or not.

So when I have a case of a parent/child set-up in my menu, so that the `ISLEAF` value for `Parent` is `0` and `Child` is `1`, but I have actually made the Child menu option inactive, my `'>'` symbol still displays at the parent level, even though the child record for this parent is inactive.

Any idea how I can check this alongside with the `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` value, to prevent the `'>'` symbol appearing even though this parent menu option has an inactive child record?

Basically want something that, if a child record exists based on `ISLEAF` value but child record is inactive, then ignore this leaf record and pretend it doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
CONNECT BY
        parent = PRIOR id
        AND active = 1
```

This will select a child only if it's active, if that's what you want.

Note that this query will return `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` for the items that do not have active children, and they will probably be treated as endpoints in your design.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi - didn't realise that you could add condtions at this level. All good now.